# Why isn't Spring caching a method?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, caching

Im new to Spring caching and have been working from the [examples here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/). Can someone help me figure out why this method isn't caching?

**EDIT**

After a lot of reading my theory is that I need to tell Spring to cache things in a cache file, that I dont currently have

```
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

//http://www.ehcache.org/blog/2016/05/18/ehcache3_jsr107_spring.html
//https://github.com/gibsong/ehcache-jsr107-spring

@Path("/helloservice")
@EnableCaching
public class HelloService{

    @GET
    @Path("/cache")
    @Produces({"text/plain"})
    //@CachePut(cacheNames=cacheName, key="testCache")
    @Cacheable(cacheName)
    public String testCache(){
        String start=LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
        try {
            long time = 3000L;
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        String end=LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));

        return "started: "+start+"\nended: "+end;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml (using a WildFly deployment server)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sentiment360</groupId>
    <artifactId>QuteeDemoRest</artifactId>
    <version>v1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>QuteeDemoRest</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

        <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
      <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.14.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-links -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-links</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ehcache/ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
          <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                      <!--SPRING-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Spring isn't managing that class, Jersey is.

Comment: I get that, but I was under the impression that Spring implemented the @cacheable annotation, so if there was a caching issue it was a Spring problem.... Am I wrong about that?

Comment: There is some Jersey-Spring integration but you are mixing those two together - as @chrylis pointed out. Can't you use Spring MVC to create your REST endpoint?

Comment: I could, but Im having trouble finding an example of Spring that does WEB PAGE caching (as in connect to deployment server and visit webpage to cache it) to use as a model.

Comment: First `@EnableCaching` should be on a `@Configuration` class. Second you are adding `@Cachable` to a non-spring managed bean. It is managed by Jersey and not Spring and as such the `@Cacheable is doing nothing as it is being ignored. Also what you want web-page caching isn't what you achieve with this. This is caching the result of the method not the rendered page.